Do I still need the <module>cn1libs</module> listing in my Codename One Project?
I have created a fresh CN1 Project, updated the pom file to 7.0.156, and rebuilt the project. The pom has a "Cannot resolve symbol 'cn1libs'" error at module cn1libs. I tried to install the cn1libs using the maven cn1:installcn1libs and got Failed to execute goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.156:installcn1libs (default-cli) on project taapp-javase: Execution default-cli of goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.156:installcn1libs failed. Do I still need the reference to the cn1libs, and if so, how do I get past this issue? Also, the build has a failure "CSS> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"". Do I need to manually load the slf4j file for the css? The simulator runs the Hello World app correctly. Thanks.

Can you paste the full plugin log in a gist and include the link here?

https://gist.github.com/curtjacobs1/d3c71fb57ef4f119d6ba49db9964e059

The file is invalid. The idea of using a gist is to paste the raw text from the log there. No need for zip.

Here are the build.log and idea.log from 8.13. I did the fresh build and update on the 17th. https://gist.github.com/curtjacobs1/dd4a1cd2da4d1b72b4ec76a7cf3777b5

That's the intellij log. That doesn't help. I'm talking about the console output but not the filtered stuff from above. The full output you would see when going to the top level in the console.

Got it. https://gist.github.com/curtjacobs1/fa88e685cdc61eb12ad1a85d1af82304

"I have created a fresh CN1 Project,"
How did you create this project?  Was it through start.codenameone.com?  If so, was it java or kotlin, and which template.  If not, then how?
" I tried to install the cn1libs using the maven cn1:installcn1libs and got Failed to execute goal"
Can you elaborate on this point?  What cn1libs were you trying to install?

@curtjacobs1 can you re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging as suggested by the error. Then post that log using a gist? There's a null pointer exception there that might indicate the problem.

https://gist.github.com/curtjacobs1/7cb10d596b75345d746d40c93ef4145f           The failure is still in the javase target. Because many of our target users will use the desktop version of our app, I am concerned that I will be wasting my time if I bring my classes into my new frame with this error and the desktop version doesn't work. I wonder if I damaged the cn1libs I was using when I built my app and had the issue with SQLite. codenameone-core-7.0.156.jar and codenameone-javase-7.0.156.jar are both in my External Libraries folder of the app.

I pushed a workaround for this issue and we're making an additional release today so this should be resolved. But we will probably need a better fix. Please file an issue with the gist and we'll try to fix it.

Will do. I will run the update in a few days, and report back through support. FYI, I ported my classes into the new frame. Though the cn1libs identifier in the module section is still red, the app runs correctly. All 4 database tables were created in the .cn1/database folder, and I was able to add a record with an insert query and db.execute(query) command. I will keep working with SQLMap, and send in a followup report to you through the support email. Thanks


Also, the build has a failure "CSS> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"". Do I need to manually load the slf4j file for the css?

This is just a warning, and shouldn't affect the operation of the app.
As for the rest of the issues, I'm having trouble following.  Can you provide me with instructions on how to reproduce the issues you're describing?  I've tried on each of the project templates in the Codename One initailizr, and they all seem to load and build fine.

Steve, some background. IntelliJ 2024.1 MacBook Pro, M1, could not run SQLite, Shai worked better SQLite into 7.0.156. I created a new Bare Bones Java frame with the Initializer to get fresh poms. I used the Maven sidebar in IntelliJ to run the cn1 plugin goal cn1:install-codenameone to update IntelliJ to 7.0.156. I then ran cn1:installcn1libs, which turned cn1libs red in the main app pom, and gave the error listed above. The new app functions correctly in the Simulator. Shai, I will look at Steve's tutorials and run the Maven installcn1libs goal from the command line to use the -x switch.

Why were you running the installcn1libs goal?  Do you have legacy .cn1libs that you need to install?

I do not have any legacy code. Everything I have done is from last September to now in IntelliJ 2023 and now 2024. That is why I asked if I still needed the cn1libs mentioned in the modules section of the main app pom. Based on what I have seen in your and Shai's latest answers, I didn't think I still needed it. I attached the  build log in a comment to Shai's last comment above. Thanks.
